# How to find which element is clicked in a webpage when the element is not a button and non-locatable in Selenium? (HTML, Selenium)

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to click a button in a Hebrew website that requires login, using Selenium and Python.

**Update**
Thanks to @cruisepandey's inputs, it seems that the issue is with this element located inside nested iframes.

Using inspect in Chrome, I located the "button" (which is a span element):

```html
<span data-columnnum="1" data-ispersonalareaviewable="1" data-
originalmfpriority="1" data- personalareaviewposition="manage_area" data-isrequired="0" name="editOrderBtn" id="editOrderBtn" class="viewCommand 
viewSize1 viewCommandGreenBtn" data-defaultvalue="" data-showonload="1" 
data- fieldid="9536" data-link="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?
action=edit&amp;CatID=2&amp;SubCatID=1&amp;OrderID=45330517" data-viewcommandactive="1" data- originalelementname="input">  <i class="fa fa-
pencil"></i> <span class="">Edit Details</span> </span>
```

This element is inside a div. No button element anywhere in sight.
I tried to find this element using Python and Selenium by name, path, etc. I can't find any trace of it. If I find it, I hope it is possible to us `.click()` on it, since it is not a button.

I will appreciated your help.

**Trying to find it manually**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
session=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\me\chromedriver')
session.get("https://my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=personalAreaFeed&CatID=2&SubCatID=1") # This is user-password protected and won't be accessible

for x in session.find_elements_by_xpath('//span'):
    print(x.get_property('attributes'))
```

**Trying to use the name / id tags:**

```
session.find_elements_by_id('editOrderBtn')
session.find_elements_by_name('editOrderBtn')
```

These two command results in an empty list.

Comment: Can you share all your code?

Comment: What do you mean by non-locatable ?

Comment: @Prophet I will update (adding the import and webdriver lines), but the website will not be accessible as it is password protected (and in Hebrew).

Comment: @cruisepandey I mean that I can't find this element using Selenium, when trying to find it by id or name - although you can see these two attributed exist in the `span` element.

Comment: See below, that might help.

Comment: @OfirY well, currently I have no active ads on my private area on yad2 :) What element are you trying to get?

Comment: @Prophet I'm trying to open my ad (that I manage to do), and then to boost it .
You can boost your ad every 4 hours (so currently I'm experiencing with "edit details" instead), and what seems to be the boost button is actually a span element.

Comment: If it's an ad, my guess is that it's in an IFRAME. You will need to switch to that IFRAME using Selenium but also when trying to debug in Chrome dev tools. That's likely why you can't find it either way.

Comment: When you post HTML, please take a minute to use a beautifier like https://beautifytools.com/html-beautifier.php so that it's readable. Please fix the HTML formatting in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to click on `Edit Details`

the you can use the text-based locator xpath like below:

```
//span[text()='Edit Details']
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If it is unique then there are 4 ways to perform click on it using Selenium.

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Edit Details']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Edit Details']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Edit Details']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Edit Details']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thanks, so in Chrome I'm able to find this unique xpath- which is actually in Hebrew:
//span[text()='עריכת פרטים']

When trying to code it in Python as you suggested - it is not found. I was not aware of an issue with Hebrew and Selenium/Python.

Comment: I am not sure about `Hebrew`, what is it? Also, `it is not found` please share the exact error stack trace.

Comment: Hebrew is a language written right to left.
The error stack is: 
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()="עריכת פרטים"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)

Comment: It is possible that this element is inside an iframe. If this is the case, does it change your answer?

Comment: Yes If it's in iframe then we will have to switch to iframe first and then you can use the above code. but first you will have to write the code to switch to iframe first. Using explicit wait `wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe XPath here")))` should help you by pass this issue.